# Buck/boost output voltage manipulation via feedback node

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, bjt, voltage-divider, feedback

I'm designing an emitter follower circuit attached to the feedback node of a Buck/Boost SMPS in order to pull current out of the node and subsequently increase the output voltage by varying a DAC voltage, as described here: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva861/slva861.pdf. Here is the circuit I've been testing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fncUAd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where NODE2 is the Feedback node on the Buck/Boost (VFB).

Originally, the resistor divider on the feedback node was R3 = 280k and R5 = 20k, in order to achieve a voltage of 800mV. However, I need an output voltage range of 1V to 14.4V and pulling current out of the feedback node only increases the output voltage. So I replaced the resistors to achieve a starting output voltage of 1V. I found my current resistor values using the following equations:

[image: Vout]

Where Req is:

[image: Req]

I built the circuit on breadboard and replaced the Vout/VFB voltage divider with a 800mV power supply signal (since the Buck/Boost will keep the signal at 800mV). And tested the emitter voltage at 500mV increments of VDAC. Here are the results (note that I used a emitter resistor value of 1180 instead of 1194 in the actual test):

[image]

My question relates to the operation of the BJT in the context of this circuit. The emitter voltage varies fairly linearly with the DAC voltage, which is expected. However, I did not expect the voltage at the emitter to get any higher than 800mV (the voltage at the feedback node.) I was also trying to operate the BJT in its forward active mode (where VCE > VBE), but it looks like I'm operating outside of that range as soon as VDAC goes above 800mV. So what mode is the BJT operating in? Why is the voltage at the emitter greater than 800mV?

Apologies for the long report! Any feedback and thoughts are welcome!

Comment: I know this is not the answer you want, but.. why don't you just put a programmable potentiometer? In this way you can adjust the ground resistor and set whichever voltage you want. Alternatively, you can change ground in the feedback (ground of R5) for your DAC output. This way you can change the reference to whatever you want, just be careful at poweron.

Comment: A programmable pot is our backup option, this solution is cheaper when implemented in bulk.

Comment: @PaytonGrenich I don't see how your arrangement works. You want to sink current that is arriving from \$R_3\$. But the node between \$R_3\$ and \$R_5\$ must always be \$800\:\text{mV}\$. That's the game, here. \$Q_1\$ will almost always have to be heavily saturated to have any chance. And you need to lift the emitter ***above*** the collector to do the work, I suspect. That's not going to happen. This arrangement just looks wrong to me. Or am I missing something? Do you have a negative rail?

Comment: Why don't you just follow what they did in the TI app note you posted?

Comment: Or why didn't you take advice from your previous question?

Comment: I suggested going with a digital pot but my supervisor wants to go with this emitter follower circuit because of potential 'stability problems' in the output voltage of the buck/boost. Any idea why there would be stability issues with a digital pot? And if his hesitation is warranted?